# ¿Como puedo obtener el registro con fecha de creación más reciente en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, estoy intentando obtener el ultimo registro de acuerdo a la fecha de creación en mi base de datos.
Entrando un poco más en contexto tengo varios registros los cuales coinciden en todos sus campos excepto en su fecha de creación y quiero obtener de todos ellos el ultimo que ha sido creado.

Tengo el siguiente código no mostrate todo para reducir las líneas lo importante está en la consulta, esto funciona pero me trae el primer registro que coincida con mis where lo que es correcto pero también quiero que me traiga el registro con la fecha de creación más actual:

```
public function test () {
   $candidateExam = CandidateExam::where('candidate_id', $candidate->id)->where('active', false)->first();
   return $candidateExam;
}
```

¿Alguna idea o enlace a documentación? Se los agradeceria mucho, gracias.

Comment: La documentación te lo explica: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada te recomiendo siempre escribir las versiones que estes utilizando, eso va a ahorrar mucho tiempo a quienes intenten ayudarte (Por ejemplo versión de PHP y laravel)

La razón por la que te devuelve el primer registro que coincide con tu búsqueda es porque estas utilizando `->first()` eso devuelve únicamente la primera coincidencia de lo que estes buscando

En principio la idea no está mal, pero te hace falta un parámetro más en tu consulta para que devuelva únicamente la fila más reciente

Laravel tiene (Desde la versión 5.3 en adelante) dos métodos, `latest()` que ordena las filas de la más reciente a la más antigua utilizando la columna `created_at` como referencia (Esa columna aparece si estas utilizando `timestamps` en tu migración) y `oldest()` que devuelve las filas ordenadas de más antígua a más reciente (Más información [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest))

Lo que le hace falta a tu consulta es utilizar `latest()`

```
$candidateExam = CandidateExam::where('candidate_id', $candidate->id)->where('active', false)->latest()->first();
```