# Eloquent Agrupar por fechas con criterios de fecha

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente tabla y más campos, pero estos son lo que influyen en mi consulta/problema

| id | well_id | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-30 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-05-30 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-05-30 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-04-21 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-04-19 |
| 6 | 3 | 2022-04-01 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 8 | 2 | 2022-03-20 |
| 9 | 3 | 2022-03-23 |

Debo agrupar por ´well_id´ la máxima fecha encontrada, puede ser un ´well_id´ o todos, ser un rango de fecha también que quiera consultar.

He intentando esto:

```php
$dataWells =WellControl::select('*', DB::raw('MAX(fecha) as ultima_fecha'))
                    ->where('area_id', 1)
                    ->whereBetween('fecha' ,[$fechaDesde, $fechaHasta])
                    ->groupBy('well_id')
                    ->get();
```

Me agrupa bien, me selecciona el rango de fechas, pero me arroja primera fecha que encuentra, no la última que necesito.

Comment: Buen día, yo creo que te hace falta utilizar `latest`, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/514875/171630) y tal vez [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/519155/171630) que habla de `whereDate`. Si alguna de las dos te sirve, avísanos para relacionar tu pregunta con la otra.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato muchas gracias, ahora si, con latest funciona perfecto

Comment: Perfecto! Voy a marcar tu pregunta como duplicada de esta otra, [¿Como puedo obtener el registro con fecha de creación más reciente en Laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513992/como-puedo-obtener-el-registro-con-fecha-de-creaci%c3%b3n-m%c3%a1s-reciente-en-laravel). Esto relacionará tu pregunta con la otra. Saludos!